# No Such Module even after installing the framework via cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cocoapods

I am trying to integrate a framework/library for creating appealing forms in iOS, using this one: https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms

I was able to install Cocoapods. I also added the following in my Podfile (in my project's directory):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftForms'
```

And run the command: `$ pod install`

But in my class, I still get 'No such module 'SwiftForms'.
[image]

And what does the color red indicates here:
[image]

When I open the xworkspace, I get these errors:
[image]

Comment: as i can see in screenshot you used `project.xcodeproj` to open your project . Use `project.xcworkspace` to open

Comment: I still get errors. See updated question.

Comment: it seems you are missing some import. Do you have UIKit imported?

Comment: Can you try adding target to your podfile like this: target 'YourProject' do
pod 'SwiftForms'
end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just created a sample app to understand your issue.

Just follow these steps carefully.

**Step.1** *Updated my **Podfile** with **SwiftForms** Lib*

> platform :ios, '8.0'
>
> use_frameworks!
>
> **pod 'SwiftForms'**

**Step.2** **Open terminal** at Podfile's parent folder and run command

> pod install

**Step.3** open **project_name.xcworkspace** file to open Project with pods

**Step.4** Go to *Project Settings* --> *Build Phases* --> Add **SwiftForms.framework**

[image]

**Step.5** Now goto the Viewcontroller.swift and import

```
import UIKit
import SwiftForms


class ViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

It works like charm!! let me know if you find any trouble in this.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the "Build Active Architectures Only" to No, in main project and Pods subproject helped me to fix the above error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43557775/5177699