# Error "No such module" when installed framework with pod in swift 3

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I had manually added Alamofire, realm and swiftjson framework in my swift project. At that time my project was working properly.

Now I created a Podfile in my project directory and added the following pods

```
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'RealmSwift’
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
```

It is successfully installed.
I opened .xcworkspace and tried to import the framework. But is showing error message "No such module Realmswift", "No such module Alamofire", "No such module SwiftyJson".

Framework search paths are as follows:

```
$(inherited)
$(PROJECT_DIR)/app_name/Frameworks
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

Even "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to NO.
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you opening your project by WorkSpace ?

Comment: @ Aashish1aug : yes i am opening workspace

Comment: Should it not be `$(SRCROOT)` (recursive)?

Comment: @Mundi: but $(PROJECT_DIR) is also a directory of project.

Comment: Hi @ashwinitechnopurple, did you find a solution? I am seeing the same error, but only after creating a new build scheme and configuration. Other schemes/configs build ok, but new one can't find modules.

Comment: Hi @BJMiller, did you find a solution to the above problem, I am having same issue and tried different way still could not solve. If you solved it please suggest the ideas.
Thank you!

Comment: Hey @PurushottamPadhya, this was a while ago so I apologize for not remembering any specific details, but I don't recall having the problem anymore. I vaguely remember trying a fresh `Podfile` from a template, and adding the needed pods in the relevant target memberships. Then of course, run `pod install`, clean Xcode, close Xcode, clear derived data, and rebuild project in Xcode. Give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Build Active Architectures Only` to `No` in Pods subproject also. It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `pod install` in your project directory?